# load_weights returns a non callable value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using model subclassing to define my model and to load weights for my neural network with a custom training function. Because of subclassing, I cannot use `model.load` and `model.save`.

My subclass to load weights looks like this:

```
def load_W_1(self, filepath, inputs):
    x=self.call(inputs)
    x=self.load_weights(filepath)
    return x


def call(self, inputs, training=True):

    x = self.conv_1(inputs)
    x = self.leakyrelu_1(x)
    x = self.dropout_1(x, training)

    x = self.conv_2(x)
    x = self.batch_norm_1(x, training)
    x = self.leakyrelu_2(x)
    x = self.dropout_2(x, training)

    x = self.flatten(x)

    return self.out(x)
```

The reason I call the `self.call` in my `load_weights()` function is otherwise I have issues with layer counts in `load_weights()`.

To call my function, I then execute the following lines:

```
discriminator=discriminator.load_W_1(filepath2, my_image)
```

Here, `filepath2` is the location of my .h5 file while my_image is some arbitrary tensor to fit the dimensions (You are trying to load a weight file containing 11 layers into a model with 10 layers.)

But in my training function, I have a line to call the discriminator training as

```
disc_loss += train_discriminator(images)
```

which leads into the following function

```
def train_discriminator(images):
        noise = tf.random.normal([batch_size, latent_dim])

        with tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
            generated_imgs = generator(noise, training=True)
```

But pointing to:

```
disc_loss += train_discriminator(images)
```

I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

My guess is that this is because the model gets replaced by it's weights when I call the load_weights function but I don't know how to work around it either. I need to let it train with these trained h5s.

the full traceback path

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-cdbe6daa184b> in <module>()
    140 
    141 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 142     train()
    143     #train_on_batch

9 frames
<ipython-input-110-cdbe6daa184b> in train()
    104             g_temp,d_temp, temp_all=list(),list(),list()
    105 
--> 106             disc_loss += train_discriminator(images)
    107             d_temp.append(disc_loss)
    108             d_all.append(disc_loss)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    501       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    502       initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
--> 503       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
    504     finally:
    505       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    406     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    407         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 408             *args, **kwds))
    409 
    410     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1846     if self.input_signature:
   1847       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1848     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1849     return graph_function
   1850 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2148         graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2149         if graph_function is None:
-> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2039             arg_names=arg_names,
   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2042         self._function_attributes,
   2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    913                                           converted_func)
    914 
--> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    916 
    917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    356         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    360 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    903           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    904             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 905               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    906             else:
    907               raise

TypeError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-110-cdbe6daa184b>:59 train_discriminator  *
        generated_output = discriminator(generated_imgs, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py:394 converted_call
        return py_builtins.overload_of(f)(*args, **kwargs)

    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Edir: just changed
`discriminator=discriminator.load_W_1(filepath2, my_image)`

to `discriminator.load_W_1(filepath2, my_image)`

Now it trains but with the initial values, there seems to be no loading of weights

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback for your error?

Comment: will reddit the question with the full traceback

Comment: disc_loss is a variable that stores losses

Comment: Your `train_discriminator` function doesn't return anything, is it supposed to?

Comment: load_weights does not return anything, that is your core misunderstanding.

Comment: It's supposed to return a value, it was until I started playing with ```load_weights``` I made some changes to ```load_weights``` and now it works, but starts from begininning

Comment: @Matias, I just realised that. When I did ```discriminator=discriminator.load_weights``` I was getting a none based issue. Right now, I tried changing it to ```discriminator.load_weights``` and the losses return to their epoch zero values. So loading doesn't have the desired outcome even with the added functions

Comment: Never mind, it was my mistake, I accidentally re-saved the wrong weights